# How to convert html page to base 64 string

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using **Angular 6** for my project, in my index page I'm binding data and submit it to db, I want to submit whole html page with bonded data to db as string.

Can I know how to convert html page to base 64 string?

Comment: See how to convert string to base64 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript then you make your whole html as one string then convert it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get you Markup as a string with,

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

And then convert that string to base64 using `btoa()` like this,

```
var encoded = window.btoa(markup);
```

Or if you get UTF8, use this,

```
var encoded = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(markup)));
```

Comment: its working but when i put big contain indo btoa(); the console get this error, can i know how to fix this
Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
Error: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(markup)))` I believe this will solve your issue.

Comment: Pleasure, you can accept the answer as well by clicking the tick icon :P

Answer (score 2):

You can get the HTML as string of any website with

```
window.document.documentElement.innerHTML
```